# Canceling a Lwt. thread

Tags: multithreading, ocaml, lwt

I can't for the life of me find a way to handle the canceling of an lwt thread.

Here is what I have, simplified.

```
#require "lwt.unix, lwt.ppx"
open Lwt.Infix

let program =
  let counter = ref 1 in
  let can_cancel = fst (Lwt.task ()) in

  Lwt.async_exception_hook := (fun _ ->
    prerr_endline "some exception");

  Lwt.on_cancel can_cancel (fun () ->
            Lwt_io.printl "correct ending" |> Lwt.ignore_result);

  Lwt.async begin fun () ->
    let rec forever () =

      try%lwt
        Lwt_io.printl "Hello World" >>= fun () ->

        if !counter = 3 then Lwt.cancel can_cancel
        else counter := !counter + 1;
        Lwt_unix.sleep 0.5 >>= forever
      with
        Lwt.Canceled -> Lwt_io.printl "canceled inside function"
    in

    Lwt.catch forever begin function
      | Lwt.Canceled -> Lwt_io.printl "Cancled exception happened"
      | _ -> Lwt.return ()
    end
  end;
  can_cancel

let () =
  Lwt_main.run program
```

You can see my several attempts to catch the Canceled exception, none of which work. 
My output is

```
utop cancelable.ml                                                     ⏎
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
correct ending
Exception: Lwt.Canceled.
```

In the grander scheme of things, I have a `unit Lwt.t list ref`, which were created with `Lwt.task`, and then I plan on doing `List.iter Lwt.cancel` on the list, then replacing it with new threads of type `unit Lwt.t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was putting the try/with at the wrong level.

This code shows the right place to put the try/with for the Lwt.Canceled exception

```
#require "lwt.unix, lwt.ppx"
open Lwt.Infix

let program =
  let counter = ref 1 in
  let can_cancel = fst (Lwt.task ()) in

  Lwt.async begin fun () ->
    let rec forever () =
        Lwt_io.printl "Hello World" >>= fun () ->
        if !counter = 3 then Lwt.cancel can_cancel
        else counter := !counter + 1;
        Lwt_unix.sleep 0.5 >>= forever
    in
    forever ()
  end;
  can_cancel

let () =
  try
    Lwt_main.run program
  with
    Lwt.Canceled -> Lwt_io.printl "ended" |> Lwt.ignore_result
```